# Where are APN configs saved in Android?

Tags: root-access, apn

I want to know where exactly are stored the APNs that are **added by the user** on Android. I want to edit them manually using X-plore (or any other root file explorer).

I know that in `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml` are stored the APN that come preset with the device, but I'm looking for the XML file where the user added APN are stored instead.

Comment: For anyone else arriving here to find out how Android automatically picks up APNs, the APN preset configurations are now found in /etc/apns-conf.xml, and are linked to a SIM that is inserted by the mmc and mnc.

Comment: @Bilko `/etc` is a symlink to `/system/etc`. Both files are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on your ROM .I recently checked mine and are in the following folder:

*/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/.*(telephony.db). You can try opening this .db file as text with a suitable file explorer and see if you can find them. (**These are apns in the ROM by default**)

**Edit**

I created a test apn manually and did a search, I learnt that its actually stored here:  ***/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.x­ml***

(This xml also contains a lot of information found in settings but if you use a keyword search to try and find your manual apn, it will be much faster)

Some of the carrier apns happen to be auomatically added when you insert a new sim card, corresponding to the country, that is why they are stored in telephony database,I reckon. I hardly enter these apns manually even when I change a SIM card.

Comment: +1 On Android 9 manually added APNs are only added to `telephony.db`, `com.android.settings_preferences.x­ml` doesn't exist.

Comment: I rooted my phone running android 10 with Magisk and used the app SQLite Editor to add dun to my APN and bypass my hotspot limit. In the app I found the APN at: /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db/carriers Once there I just searched for my specific carrier and edited the type field by adding dun.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at a Pixel 3a device running Android 10 the location is `data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db`
`user_de` is the _**d**_evice _**e**_ncryption related user directory, use `user` instead if the phone does not support this

Not strictly related to the question about the user provided storage location, but this might be useful for people landing here after a search:

When looking in [TelephonyProvider](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r7/xref/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/src/com/android/providers/telephony/TelephonyProvider.java#625) there are 4 different locations with increasing precedence:

- Default APNs: /system/etc/apns-conf.xml
- OEM APNs: /oem/telephony/apns-conf.xml
- OTA Update APNs: /data/misc/apns/apns-conf.xml
- Product APNs: /product/etc/apns-conf.xml

**Note:** In Android 10 the system partition cannot be mounted read-write. Use a Magisk module to change the APNs or update the APN under `/data/misc/apns/apns-conf.xml`. This path is writable after an `su`.

The APNs are finally stored in database `/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db`. Like mentioned above be flexible here about the `user_de` part.

Also take note that an `ApnSourceService` method was introduced in Android 10(?). This is a vendor specific implementation to lookup APNs. This is a not documented service. If this service is active all the XMLs will be ignored. Use a Magisk module to turn off this service if needed.

Comment: `/data/user_de` is correct, it's the Device Encrypted storage on devices with FBE support. Many configurations have moved from `/data/user` (`/data/data`) to this encrypted path.

Comment: Thanks. I have improved the answer here.