# Find APNSourceService

Tags: services, apn, telephony, smartwatch

I have a TicWatch Pro 4G. As some may know, the watch only supports Vodafone. But from what I have seen, that's mostly down to the fact of the correct APN for other networks not being available. After looking in the usual places like /system/etc/apns-conf.xml, I found most APNs to be present there. However, the menu to choose the APN is always empty. After a lot of digging, I found this thread on here:

[Where apn configs are saved in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170634/where-apn-configs-are-saved-in-android/170656)

In there, it is mentioned that there is such a thing called "ApnSourceService". However, there is basically no information available on this except that thread and some mentions in the source code, one of them being in the TelephonyProvider.
In that thread, it was said, that one can disable such a Service using Magisk. However, I found no information on which service that might be, or where to find any clues. Also I looked into system-apks to find any mention, but I didn't find something useful.
I also tried listing running services, but at least I didn't find something useful in there.

Also I'm not really a professional, it might well be I'm completely on the wrong path with the "ApnSourceService".
Thanks for any help